# Problems with game background

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a game and trying to set a background for my game. This is the code:

```
    playerLight.enabled = true
    playerLight.categoryBitMask = 1
    playerLight.falloff = 1
    playerLight.ambientColor = SKColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 0.5)
    playerLight.lightColor = SKColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.01)
    playerLight.shadowColor = SKColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.05)
    playerLight.position = CGPoint(x: alien.position.x, y: alien.position.y)
    self.addChild(playerLight)

    background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "underwater_background")
    background.xScale = self.frame.width
    background.yScale = self.frame.height
    background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    background.zPosition = 10
```

Th background comes out, but it is all black and covers everything on the screen. I think the black is because of the shader, but I am not sure. It  sill covers everything except for the button and player when I set the zPosition to 1 or 0. Any help? (if you need to rest of the code please ask, I didn't want to cover the screen)

Thanks,
James

Comment: As long as you place all your code into 1 code block, you wont cover the screen, SO has methods to add a scrollbar inside of it.  as for your image,  you do realize that your background is the size of the image * the size of the scene, which may end up being really big

Comment: I may be wrong, but it looks like you're setting the light color to black? Wouldn't that make the background, well, black?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thanks for the advice! The sprite was oversized.

Comment: @LandSeagull Ohhhh. That may be right. Do you know how to turn off the lighting for a specific sprite?